# Center of $G$ can be infinite Yes/No

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is the following statement true/false

> let $p$ be  a prime number.Let $G$  be a group such that  for  each $ g \in G$ there exists an $ n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $g^{p^n}=1$.Then the center of  $G$ can be infinite

**My attempt** : I think this  statement is true

Take  $G=\mathbb{Q}/{\mathbb{Z}}$

Every element of $\mathbb{Q}/{\mathbb{Z}}$ is finite

Also , $\mathbb{Q}/{\mathbb{Z}}$ is an abelian group $\implies Z(G) =G$

Comment: $G$ must be a p-group.

Comment: In your example $\frac 1 6+\mathbb Z$ is of order 6, which is not $p^n$ for any $p,n$ ($p$ prime).

Comment: @Peter take  $2/3 +\mathbb{Z} \implies |2/3|=3$ is a prime number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the [Prüfer group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group)
$$\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)=\{e^{2\pi im/p^n}\in\mathbb{C}\mid n\in\mathbb{N},~m=0,1,\ldots,p^n-1\}.$$
This is an infinite multiplicative abelian group, and each element has finite order $p^n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Note for OP: for each prime $p$, the Prüfer group is a (Sylow) subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ via the identification 
$$
\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty) \cong \mathbb{Z}\Bigl[\frac1p\Bigr]/\mathbb{Z} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Your example does not satisfy the requirements as pointed out in the comments.

So let's construct one example using some set operations. We are done if we construct an infinite Abelian group $G$ such that every non identity element is of order $2$.

Consider a nonempty set $X$ and take its power set $P(X)$. Check that

$P(X)$ is an Abelian group with the operation "symmetric difference", i.e., for $A,B\in P(X)$, define $A\triangle B:= (A-B)\bigcup (B-A)$. The identity of this group is as one would expect -the empty set $\emptyset$.

With this, note that for any $A\in P(X), A\triangle A=\emptyset$, whence $A=A^{-1}$. So every element is an inverse of itself. This implies that every non identity element of the Abelian group $(P(X), \triangle)$ is of order $2$.

Now take $X=$ any infinite set $(\mathbb N$ for example), then $(P(X), \triangle)$ is an infinite Abelian group for which $Z(P(X))= P(X)$ and that
$A^2=1$ for every $A\in P(X)$.

Answer (score 0):

Any infinite cyclic group is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$ so $Z(G)=G$ so center would be automatically infinite.

For your statement: Consider $\mathbb Z_5$. In that case $p=5$. Of course $\exists n \in \mathbb N$ such that $(g^p)^n =1$ for every $g\in G$ because our group of order $p$ which is finite but its center is not infinite.